# Onclick not added until after Postback

Tags: asp.net, javascript

I have the following:

```
<asp:Button id="SubmitButton" Text="Submit" runat="server" OnClientClick="Do();"  
     OnClick="SubmitButton_Click"/>
```

When the page is first rendered, I go to the view source in my browser and see that the `onclick="Do();"` is not added to my submit button tag. But when I do a post back, and do the view source again, the `onclick` is added to the submit.

Why would the `onclick` not be there on the first request?

Comment: This is definitely supposed to work on non-postback pageviews too - are you sure you don't have any code that edits the attributes somewhere?

Comment: Positive, I had to add the following server side code to make it work: SubmitButton.Attributes.Add("onclick", "Do();");

Comment: Can you post your server side code?

Answer (score 0):

At least on my machine, I can see OnClick event on both request.